# nsIXMLHttpRequest executes only till readyState 1

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am using the following script to load some data through the firefox extension UI.

```
var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();
var www = "http://localhost/view?url=http://google.com";
req.open('GET', www, true);

if (req.readyState){
    alert(req.readyState);
}
```

It alerts just 1.
The script shows no error in the error console with the strict javascript being enabled.

Comment: Could have something to do with your use of alert(). Try just using window.dump instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- You've forgotten to call `req.send(null)`. The request will only execute when you call [`send()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29).
- You're doing an asynchronous request, because you specified [the third parameter for `open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) to be `true`. This means that by the time you request the `readyState`, the request will still be executing. You should instead use a readystatechange listener as so:

  ```
  req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
          if(req.status == 200)
              dump(req.responseText);
          else
              dump("Error loading page\n");
      }
  };
  ```

I suggest taking a look at [the documentation on Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), which contains the example above and several others.

Comment: ah! what silly mistakes I made. :( how can i forget readystatechange, now it looks so obvious to me that why it just alerts 1. thnx :)

Comment: No problem. It's often easy to overlook something, and taking a fresh perspective helps. Did it fix your problem?

Comment: No, I hadn't heard of it before. I'm only the developer of [TryAgain](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2462/), and like to tinker some in XUL on the side. I've noticed that you haven't marked any of your questions answered. Please do so, so that others can benefit from this exchange, too.